# VBA outlook - set up from box

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm using the following VBA script to send an email from outlook. Work smooth. Only thing is I would also like to set up my from sender. I use two one called "Marc" and one called "bedrijfsbureau" (see picture: http://www.flickr.com/photos/112983354@N05/12344745935/)

Anybody idea how I can set that up? Code underneath gives an error with my .from

```
Sub SendMessage()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim var1 As String
Dim sentto As String

sentto = "Referentenrapportage"


Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


var1 = InputBox("Zet hier neer welke maand het is")

    With OutMail
    .From = Bedrijfsbureau
    .To = sentto
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "SENS referentenrapportage Maand" & var1
    .Body = "Beste SDM'er, Bijgevoegd de SENS sterrenrapportage van maand" & var1


    .Display
    End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing that error because `.From` is not a valid property of the `MailItem` object. ([See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn320330.aspx) for a complete list of `MailItem` properties.)

If you want to send the email `on behalf of` Bedrijfsbureau, you need to use the `MailItem` object property `SentOnBehalfOfName`. For example, you would use it like this:

```
With OutMail
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "Bedrijfsbureau@yourcompany.com"
    'Other code
End With
```

If you have two different *accounts*, and you want to use the second account, you'll need to know the account number of Bedrijfsbureau. [Ron de Bruin](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/account.htm) has a great article that covers this in detail (along with some sample code). I highly recommend you check it out.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ARich. However when I try I get this: http://www.flickr.com/photos/112983354@N05/12359729565/. I'm using office 2003. Could it be that that's the case?

Comment: Which line is highlighted when that error is thrown?